# Display text from textarea on submit button - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Q] I'm basic Developer , How to display text from textarea on submit button using angular-js ?

I have current code with me :-

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.pass = $scope.list;
        $scope.text = 'Share your knowledge !';
        $scope.submit = function() {
            if ($scope.text) {
                $scope.pass.push($scope.text);
            }
        };
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <br>
                <textarea style="resize:initial;" type="" ng-model="text" name="text"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input align="right" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:120px; align:right;" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                <pre>{{list}}</pre>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code just display's messages from textarea in an array format.

But i just want a single text message to be printed/displayed . How can that be achieved ? Thank you .

Comment: What do you mean by _single text message_. ? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: That's because you're pushing the text in to an array -> `$scope.pass.push`. To get a string, do `$scope.pass.join('');`

Comment: I just want to show a message after clicking submit button , without showing it in an array format   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you only want to display the current message which is in textarea. If so do this:

```
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.pass = [];
        $scope.text = 'Share your knowledge !';
        $scope.submit = function() {
            if ($scope.text) {
                $scope.pass.push($scope.text);
                $scope.list = $scope.text;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `text` as value of the `textarea`.
When from is submitted set the value of textarea.

I guess you want the message in textarea to show in `list` after form submit.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.list = '';
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        $scope.pass = $scope.list;
        $scope.text = 'Share your knowledge !';

        $scope.submit = function() {
            $scope.list = $scope.text;
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        };
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <br>
                <textarea style="resize:initial;" type="" ng-model="text" name="text"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input align="right" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:120px; align:right;" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                <pre>{{list}}</pre>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry , you didn't got my question right . my mistake though ...  i dont want the text on submit button , but the text should display onclick submit function on screen without showing it in an array format .

Comment: yup , just wanted to show a single message after clicking submit button , without in an array .

Comment: Thanks Buddy 90% got what i wanted , but " [ ] " are still comming how to remove that ?  :)

Comment: @vikrant Check updated answer. Notice: `$scope.list = '';` added

Comment: Thanks buddy  ^_^  achieved what i wanted :)